# Google analytics error message 'Unexpected error. please try again later'

Tags: google-analytics

When trying to save a filter to a GA dashboard widget I am getting the error message 'Unexpected error. please try again later'.

The widget I am having a problem with is the 'show landing pages for Facebook referrals' widget. 
Here are the parameters I set...

Display the following columns:
Page title
Unique pageviews

Filter this data:
Only show 'Social source referral' Exactly matching Yes
Only show  'Social network' Exactly matching Facebook

Up to this point I can save the widget.

Now...its the following filter that is causing the problem.

Only show 'Page' Regular expression
twwdcqgfk1|u0evfggft91b|u0qpgfgfgy64z|u2lfgfgfhrnsg1|u4d5aerwwrhoz|u6mwwwrr39tiz|u8tr5hfs2st5z

The above is only a sample of the ids, I use about 450 ids in the regular expression field.
When I use this filter on other widgets in the same dashboard and in widgets of other dashboards it works fine but on a few I get the error when trying to save  'Unexpected error. please try again later'.

If I just use two ids in the regular expression field i.e. u4d5aerwwrhoz|u6mwwwrr39tiz I can save the widget with the 'page' filter - however if I add more than two ids that's I cannot save.

I can't figure it out, i've tried saving this filter using multiple browsers, on different pc's, at different times but I cant get it to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why the report won't work is [quite simple](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#q_details) :-)

> Regular Expressions — You can also use regular expressions in filter
>   expressions using the =~ and !~ operators. Their syntax is similar to
>   Perl regular expressions and have these additional rules: **Maximum
>   length of 128 characters — Regular expressions longer than 128
>   characters result in a 400 Bad Request status code returned from the
>   server.**

The workaround from my experience is to use API and run several queries so that you can stay within the limits. But it's pain in the ass...

If there is some simpler pattern -- I checked and all of the posted IDs have 13 characters, so maybe you could use regular expression checking the number of characters. Something like:

```
.*\?^facebookAdId=.{13}$/
```

The curly brackets are the way to check the number of occurrences. This could probably help.

Comment: Thanks Petr, what a relief to understand what the probelm is. Unforunately not only do the ids have different character lengths but I also need to filter 450 ids out of a list of 2000 so I need to be able to filter the ids in the widgets. The pages on our website are flat (at the same level) and not in directories so the only way to report on groups of pages is to filter the ids. Each page has a unique id. I just did a character count of all the ids and it comes to 6300. Any other way to create a filter? Going the api route is not an option for me i'm afraid. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you considered 3rd party tools like NextAnalytics or Analytics Canvas? They make it easier to filter things down... What you could also do is to list all the campaign IDs with metrics you need in Excel, then on a separate sheet list all the IDs you want to filter, duplicate the columns and with lookup() function get the metrics for only the IDs that are on the second sheet: http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/lookup-reference-functions.html I think this would be very practical and not that time consuming :)

Comment: Also, API is not that hard, you don't have to do any programming :) Try the query builder (http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253Acampaign%252Cga%253Asource%252Cga%253Amedium&metrics=ga%253Avisits%252Cga%253Abounces%252Cga%253AgoalCompletionsAll&filters=ga%253Amedium%253D%253Dcpc&sort=ga%253Avisits&start-date=2013-11-01&end-date=2013-12-31) and play around a bit to get the data you need to work with...

Comment: Thanks for your help Petr, i'll look onto the options you mentioned.

Comment: Glad I could help - I am preparing an how-to article on similar topic, will post it here in few days (hopefully :-)